# unsigned long and atoi in C

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned, number-systems

Code:

```
char temp[] = "1010000001010011";
printf("%s\n", temp);
unsigned long num = atoi(temp);
printf("%lu\n", num);
```

Output:

```
1010000001010011
4081617243
```

Why is num not 41043?

Comment: `atoi` is for decimal numbers not binary. Use `strtol` for binary.

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: `atoi()` interprets its input as a string representation of a *decimal* number.  If you want to be convert a number expressed in a different base -- say base 2 -- then use `strtol()`.

Comment: Note also that when interpreted as a decimal number, your input string very likely exceeds your system's largest representable `long` value.

Comment: "Why is num not 41043?" What's 41043 and what does it have to do with anything?

Comment: @AnT isn't is completely obvious that `41043` is the decimal value of binary `1010000001010011`?

Comment: @Weather Vane: Firstly, no, it is not obvious. Secondly, no, I did not downvote.

Comment: @AnT what is more obvious is that OP wanted a conversion from binary, and it's a small step to a calculator.

Comment: Thanks for the help...seems I need to convert to decimal in the char* before atoi...

Answer (score 2):

`atoi("1010000001010011");` attempts to convert the text as a sequence of *decimal* characters to an `int`.  If `int` was wide enough, it would take on the decimal value of 1,010,000,001,010,011.  Not surprisingly, that value is outside OP's `int` range, so the result is *undefined behavior* or UB.

To convert the string as if it was *binary* characters, use `strtol()` or `strtoul()`

```
char temp[] = "1010000001010011";
char *endptr;
int base = 2;
unsigned long ulnum = strtoul(temp, &endptr, base);
if (endptr == temp) puts("No conversion");
else printf("%lu\n", ulnum);  // 41043
```

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` returns an `int` value. The decimal number `1010000001010011` which is hex `39696F348895B` does not fit a 32-bit variable and was truncated to hex `F348895B` which is the signed decimal value `-213350053`. However it is undefined behaviour to assign that value to `unsigned long`, although the compiler produced code that does assign that bit pattern, which as `unsigned long` happened to be `4081617243`.

**Many thanks to @[AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/ant) and to @chux**

Comment: Overflow in `atoi` results in *undefined behavior*, not in truncation.

Answer (score -2):

Beacouse `atoi()` converts the string into an integer, does not convert from binary.
For example the code

```
char str[]="123";
printf("%d",atoi(str));
```

will print 123 as an integer